# Calling redirect post method keeps appending values to request param

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having a strange problem that I can not figure out:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView createUser(@RequestParam(value = "message", required = false) String message) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    mav.addObject("message", message);
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RedirectView use(RedirectAttributes ret,  @RequestParam("message") String message) {
    // does something with the message
    ret.addAttribute("message", message);

    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
    redirectView.setContextRelative(true);
    redirectView.setUrl("/user");
    return redirectView;
}
```

Here I simply get some input from the user, mess around with the input, redirect back to the get handler. The problem arises when I do post requests: for some reason, values from the previous requests are saved.

For example, if the user input 'a' in the first request, 'a' is observed in the get request. However, if the user inputs 'b' in the second request, the string 'a,b' is observed. If the user inputs 'c' in the third request, then 'a,b,c' is observed.

I have been trying to figure out this problem for the longest times. I have some requirements, such as not being allowed to use `flash attributes` (I cant use HTTPSession).

Any help would be really appreciated, and maybe some explanation for this bug too!

Answer (score 0):

In `redirectView` the previous query properties are propagated, that's why they are getting appended to previous attributes

for more details see the [RedirectView Documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html)

Comment: is there a way to only get the most recent query property?

Comment: try returning "redirect:url" string instead of `RedirectView`. e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_page_redirection_example.htm

Comment: I'm still having the same problem with returning string "redirect:/user" as values are still being propagated